# How to make a nested dictionary form a given file?

Tags: python

I have a big text file which I need to convert into a nested dictionary. My .txt file contents are like below:
test.txt

```
student-a-b-c-d-e
math-78-69-43-89-91
physics-74-65-47-88-93
chemistry-76-66-49-87-92
```

I need to make a nested dictionary of a format like:

```
{a:{math: 78, physics: 74, chemistry: 76}, b:{math: 69, physics: 65, chemistry: 66}, c:{math: 43, physics: 47, chemistry: 49}, d:{math: 89, physics: 88, chemistry: 87}, e:{math: 91, physics: 93, chemistry: 92}}
```

I am not good at file handling. I tried to make a list and then make it dictionary, but not sure if I am doing it right.

```
studentdict = {}
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
namelist = = (file.readline()).rstrip().rsplit('-')
namelist = namelist[1:]
for name in namelist:
    studentdict[name]= {} # {a:{}, b:{} etc}
wholestringlist = (file.readlines())
file.close()
freqlist = []
for item in wholestringlist:
    freqlist.append(item.rstrip().rsplit('-'))
wholestringlist.clear()
subjectlist = [freqlist[i][0] for i in range(len(freqlist))] #['math', 'physics', 'chemistry']
valuelistold = [freqlist[i][1:] for i in range(len(freqlist))]
```

Some hints would be useful to guide me in the right track.

Comment: Can you use external modules? @Survo

Comment: Maybe not. Previously I tried in another exercise importing popular modules like numpy and the grader says that it doesn't have it. However, Many thanks if you can solve by importing any class, at least I can figure out the algorithm.

Comment: You should use a `.json` file for converting into dictionaries, since JSON files are basically one big dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
mydict = {}
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    # Treat first line differently:
    header = f.readline()
    header = header[:-1] # remove newline character
    names = header.split("-")[1:] 
    for name in names:
        mydict[name] = {}
    
    # iterate through the remaining lines
    for l in f:
        classname = l.split("-")[0]
        grades = l.split("-")[1:]
        # associate each grade to a name with `zip``
        for name, grade in zip(names, grades):
            # remove possible newline character:
            if "\n" in grade:
                grade = grade.split("\n")[0]
            mydict[name][classname] = grade

    print(mydict)
```

Basically it first reads the first line to get the names ('a', 'b', ...) and creates a dictionary for each one of them. Then it reads line by line, reading first the class name and creating a new key in each dictionary with this value. Then the grades are read and are stored in each corresponding dictionary according to their order of appearance

Comment: Thanks! Never had any idea about zip() and it's use!

Comment: @SuvroJyotiKundu You could simulate it by using indices (`in range(len(names)`) and setting `name=names[idx]` and `grade=grades[idx]`. It may be clearer if you're not sure what `zip` exactly does.

Answer (score 1):

Populate header, index and content into respective list and then iterate.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()

header, index, content = [], [], []

for i, row_str in enumerate(data):
    row = row_str.rstrip('\n').split('-')
    if i == 0:
        header = row[1:]
    else:
        index.append(row[0])
        content.append(row[1:])

output = {
    student: { 
        subject: content[j][i] for j, subject in enumerate(index) 
    } for i, student in enumerate(header)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So dict(zip(list1, list2) can also be used to convert into respective dictionaries!

Comment: Yes. But it is a bit more time-consuming in current case. Hence, I modified the code.